# How to show unzip progress?

Tags: zip, unzip

How can I show progress, bar or percentage, when unzipping large files?

`unzip zipfile.zip` does not show any progress info?

Answer (score 25):

Without installing anything else, the easiest way is to have it print a dot for every file that is extracted or processed using awk.

```
unzip -o source.zip -d /destDirectory | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} {print "."}'
```

If it is a large zip file, then you can elect to print a dot for every 10th or 20th file like this:

```
unzip -o source.zip -d /destDirectory | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} {if(NR%10==0)print "."}'
```

Just change the "10" in the NR%10 piece to whatever increment you want.

Alternately, you can install the pv command, which doesn't work really well with unzip, but gives a one liner view that is not totally terrible.

Install pv:

```
sudo apt install pv
```

Unzip with pv:

```
unzip -o source.zip -d /destDirectory | pv -l >/dev/null
```

This shows output that looks like this:

```
28.2k 0:00:03 [9.36k/s] [        <=>                       ]
```

Because of the way that zip files are processed though, it will not show a progress bar in a meaningful way like we would wish.

Comment: Great first answer, congrats! +1

Comment: Did you see `unzip`'s `-p` option? Maybe one could use that to get a progress bar with `pv`?

Comment: Some zip files have only one compressed file. Size about 5 GB. Is there a simple way to get uncompressed size, monitor written data and show progress like 40 % or 300/5000 MB?

Comment: @JPX You can unzip to stdout using `-c` option and pipe through `pv` while telling `pv` the expected size using `-s` option, something like: `unzip -c file.zip entry | pv -s 5g > entry`.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative to show the zip/unzip progress is to use the program 7zip. In the latest version 16.02 (published 2016-05-21) it shows the progress as percentage.

The `p7zip` packages for version 16.02 are available in the Ubutuntu repository since release artuful/16.10. Older Ubuntu releases have only p7zip version 9.20.1 without progress indicator in the repository. I manually installed the pzip 16.02 version in Ubuntu xenial/16.04 from the bionic repository, there seems to be no other dependencies (p7zip, p7zip-full and p7zip-rar).

`7z x source.zip -o/destDirectory`

Note that there must be no space between the "-o" and the destination directory name.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/cli/), this is a python library but has a CLI too and will show the real progress during extraction, not only after everything's done:

```
unzip zipfile.zip | tqdm > /dev/null
```

Showing the progress as percentage is more difficult since the number of lines that `unzip` would print is unknown. Getting the number of files from the `unzip -l zipfile.zip` output is possible:

```
n_files=`unzip -l zipfile.zip | tail -n 1 | xargs echo -n | cut -d' ' -f2`
```

and then you may wish to:

```
unzip -o zipfile.zip | tqdm --desc extracted --unit files --unit_scale --total $n_files > /dev/null
```

Final output:

```
extracted: 100%|███████████████████████████████| 15126/15126 [00:00<00:00, 16218.28files/s]
```

But the output printed by unzip may not only be the extracted files' names, but also some other operations (like inflating, or linking stuff), depending on the content of your zipfile. So `n_files` does contain the right number of files, but the number of steps may be greater. Once `tqdm` gets over 100% it will switch to the default progress output, as in the first example above.

Ubuntu package name is currently `python3-tqdm`. Of course, `man tqdm` is very helpful.

Comment: I tried it on one zipfile containing a single large file and the only output was: `3it [00:31, 10.46s/it]` -- is it just measuring progress as the proportion of files unzipped?

Comment: @Desty yes I think so. If you want to measure progress corresponding to file size or things like that, you *might* make it from a python script, using tqdm, but you'd need to have an access to the information you want (that's the problem: no idea how, though) and use the update() method of the tqdm object in order to "manually" update the progress rate (in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple wrapper for that:

```sh
function punzip {
   unzip $1 | pv -l -s $(unzip -Z -1 $1 | wc -l) > /dev/null;
}
```

And then use it like follows:

```sh
$ punzip file.zip
```

It might be useful if there are a lot of small files in an archive. But if files are large, it is better to use something like this:

```sh
function plunzip {
    for f in $(unzip -Z -1 $1 | grep -v '/$');
    do
        [[ "$f" =~ "/" ]] && mkdir -p ${f%/*}
        echo "Extracting $f"
        unzip -o -c $1 $f \
            | pv -s $(unzip -Z $1 $f | awk '{print $4}') \
            > $f
    done
}
```

It will show progress bar for each individual file.

Comment: If the file to be extracted is nested in subdirectories, you may need create the directories before redirecting it.

Comment: @stackunderflow I have updated the code snippet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can watch the size of the destination directory you are unzipping your files into. For example you can use:

```
watch -n 60 du -sh dest_directory
```

where `dest_directory` is where `unzip` is writing to.

`-s` is used to show the size and `-h` is there to make it human readable. Also, this repeats this process every `60` seconds. You can change it for your setting.

Because it calls `du`(directory usage) in a loop it may be less efficient than other answers. However, if you are calling `unzip` with options like `-q`, which means `unzip` will no longer write to `stdout` and accordingly you cannot use other answers based on that, it may be your only option. It can also be faster, because `-q` will increase the speed for `unzip` when you have a large number of small files.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Scott's answer, this converts each output line to a progress indicator, and drops the newlines (alternative to `awk`):

```
unzip 'file.zip' | sed 's/.*/./' | tr -d '\n'
```

However, the pipes get buffered, so for realtime progress you need to add `stdbuf -o0`:

```
unzip 'file.zip' | stdbuf -o0 sed 's/.*/./' | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n'
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515522/455274